# E2107 Operand size mismatch

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-xe7

I use this functions since D2007 I got it online, don't remember where.

But now in XE7 it return a compilation error:

> "E2107 Operand size mismatch"

```
    function FastCharPos(const aSource : string; const C: Char; StartPos : Integer) : Integer;
    var
        L : Integer;
    begin
        //If this assert failed, it is because you passed 0 for StartPos, lowest value is 1 !!
      Assert(StartPos > 0);

        Result := 0;
      L := Length(aSource);
        if L = 0 then exit;
      if StartPos > L then exit;
      Dec(StartPos);
        asm
          PUSH EDI                 //Preserve this register

          mov  EDI, aSource        //Point EDI at aSource
          add  EDI, StartPos
                mov  ECX, L              //Make a note of how many chars to search through
                sub  ECX, StartPos
                mov  AL,  C              //and which char we want :Error -"E2107 Operand size mismatch"
        @Loop:
                cmp  Al, [EDI]           //compare it against the SourceString
          jz   @Found
          inc  EDI
                dec  ECX
                jnz  @Loop
          jmp  @NotFound
        @Found:
          sub  EDI, aSource        //EDI has been incremented, so EDI-OrigAdress = Char pos !
          inc  EDI
          mov  Result,   EDI
        @NotFound:

          POP  EDI
        end;
    end;

function FastCharPosNoCase(const aSource : string; C: Char; StartPos : Integer) : Integer;
var
  L                           : Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
    L := Length(aSource);
  if L = 0 then exit;
    if StartPos > L then exit;
  Dec(StartPos);
    if StartPos < 0 then StartPos := 0;

  asm
            PUSH EDI                 //Preserve this register
            PUSH EBX
      mov  EDX, GUpcaseLUT

      mov  EDI, aSource        //Point EDI at aSource
            add  EDI, StartPos
            mov  ECX, L              //Make a note of how many chars to search through
      sub  ECX, StartPos

            xor  EBX, EBX
            mov  BL,  C              //:Error -"E2107 Operand size mismatch"
      mov  AL, [EDX+EBX]
        @Loop:
            mov  BL, [EDI]
      inc  EDI
      cmp  Al, [EDX+EBX]
            jz   @Found
      dec  ECX
      jnz  @Loop
      jmp  @NotFound
        @Found:
      sub  EDI, aSource        //EDI has been incremented, so EDI-OrigAdress = Char pos !
      mov  Result,   EDI
        @NotFound:

      POP  EBX
            POP  EDI
    end;
end;
```

What do I need to update these two functions to XE7 win32?

What must I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code was written for pre Unicode Delphi where `Char` is an alias for `AnsiChar`, the 8 bit character type. In Delphi 2009 and later, `Char` is an alias for `WideChar` the 16 bit character type.

The reason for the error message is that the code is intended to operate on 8 bit character elements, but you are providing 16 bit operands. The operator expects 8 bit operands, but you supplied 16 bit operands.

Change `Char` to `AnsiChar` to make this code compile and behave as intended on all versions of Delphi.

Having said that, I suggest you stop using this code. Instead use [`Pos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos). As a rule, it is preferable to use built-in library functions.

Comment: Yes it's what I am doing, from D2007 to XE7, but now I need some code to just work and then I will Upgrade and clean all. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using old assembler version for string routines and use the use built-in library functions.

If you want to move on in a hurry you can reimplement you functions like this:

```
function FastCharPos(const aSource: string; const C: Char; StartPos: Integer): Integer; inline;
begin
  Result := Pos(C, aSource, StartPos);
end;

function FastCharPosNoCase(const aSource: string; C: Char; StartPos: Integer): Integer; inline;
begin
  Result := Pos(AnsiUppercase(C), AnsiUppercase(aSource), StartPos);
end;
```